# Can't access subpackages without explicitly importing them

Tags: python, package

Basically, I have some common code shared across several projects that I want to put it into it's own package to simplify distribution and make life easier when I decide to change something in the common code. Here is the structure of the package:

```
Common
    common
        util
            __init__.py
            camera.py
            math.py
        vision
            __init__.py
            contour.py
            pnp.py
        __init__.py
    ...
    LICENSE.md
    README.md
    requirements.txt
    setup.py
```

To set all this up I followed [this](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) guide from Python Packaging. I did everything up to generating the distribution archives, since my goal is to use this package as a git submodule within my projects.

You can check out the code [here](https://github.com/king-shak/Common) as well and see `setup.py`.

To install the package I run `pip install -e path/to/Common`, and it installs as expected, however when I go to import things it doesn't work as expected.

For example, if I run `import common`, and I then run `common`, I get

```
<module 'common' from 'c:\\path_to_common\\common\\common\\__init__.py'>
```

Which I expect, however if I then try running `common.util`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'common' has no attribute 'util'
```

When I was expecting something like this:

```
<module 'common.util' from 'c:\\path_to_common\\common\\common\\util\\__init__.py'>
```

**This** is the problem I'm running into. I'm still fairly new to all this, my current understanding is that if I run `common.util` I should be able to access the `util` module within `common`. (Just from using other libraries, for example with numpy, if I run `import numpy`, I can access the `linalg` module by simply running `numpy.linalg`). Am I wrong in thinking this? Or am I just setting up my package incorrectly?

(Also, I am using `setuptools.find_packages()` in `setup.py`, but that clearly isn't solving the problem, so I guess I don't fully understand what `find_packages` actually does).

I should mention, I can still access `util` if I do this:

```
import common
import common.util
common.util
```

This does yield what I want:

```
<module 'common.util' from 'c:\\path_to_common\\common\\common\\util\\__init__.py'>
```

(Also, why is everything in the path lowercase? (The drive letter and the first letter of the namespace should be uppercase). On a side note, I tried generating the distribution archives and uploading them to TestPyPI so I can download and install them (via pip) from there. Same import behavior, but the paths are correct).

But... I would prefer to get the behavior I was initially expecting working. If anyone could help me figure this out, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.  Modules that appear to exhibit different behavior have added it in explicitly, by importing it for you (e.g. in `__init__.py`).

The lowercase is because windows (which, based on your `c` drive, you are using) is case insensitive, which is not the case for linux.  Python here is choosing to make everything lower for consistency, but it could choose all upper or alternating and still work.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of messing around with ```__init__.py```, I'll definitely need to read more about it. I ended up doing my imports there and everything works as I originally intended. Thanks for the help!